# Copy HTML text from Outlook into Word using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have some Outlook VBA code that creates a Word document and pastes parts of an email which the user has selected before, e.g. (some irrelevant code parts removed)

```
Private Sub CreateDoc(M As MailItem)
Dim WApp As Word.Application, WDoc As Word.Document, I As Inspector

    Set I = M.GetInspector

    Set WApp = New Word.Application
    WApp.Visible = True
    Set WDoc = WApp.Documents.Add

    Select Case I.EditorType
    Case olEditorWord
        ' this works like a charm, even if multiple parts selected in MailItem
        I.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Copy
        WApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting

    Case olEditorHTML
        ' trouble starts here ... I don't get it ... best I came up with is
        WApp.Selection.InsertAfter I.HTMLEditor.Selection.CreateRange.Text

    Case Else
        ' unsupported formats
    End Select

    ' clean up
    Set I = Nothing
    Set WDoc = Nothing
    Set WApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

which works in Outlook 2003 and 2010

**Problem:**

My problem is in the `olEditorHTML` part where I just can't figure out how to get selected text including formats across. Best I could come up with so far is inserting plain text. Can anyone help me finding the correct code to get selected  text from the HTMLEditor into Word, including formats (just like if you manually do select/Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V).

Comment: Probably a dumb comment but what happens when you use the same code for olEditorWord with olEditorHTML?

Comment: The ´I.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Copy´ hangs with "Run-time error 91: object variable or With block variable not set" because, as one can nicely see in the debugger, the Inspector's WordEditor object ´is Nothing´

Comment: and a `I.HTMLEditor.Application.Selection.Copy` hangs with Run-time error 438: object doesn't support this property or method, because there is no Application property to the HTMLEditor object

Comment: That clears that up, it's a bit long winded but have you tried saving the word document as HTML, and then reading the text in and inserting it into the HTML email programmatically?

Comment: nope ... remember the Word Doc is the receiving edge, whereas my problem lies with the transmitting element (mail item in HTML format) ... you called it "reading in" ... where I can't get the selection including formats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for this post. Your Problem actually became a solution[for a really tricky problem] of mine.

The below line worked for me, may be it will work for you also[Incase you are still looking for a solution :)

Change the I.WordEditor.Application.Selection.Copy to I.WordEditor.Selection.Copy and it may work.

Comment: +1 for now and thank you for reviewing and answering aged posts; I am since using a kind of workaround but may have the chance to turn to this problem again in some weeks time and may then accept your answer with pleasure